# 321-avoiding permutations that start in an ascending run consisting of exactly $k$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

An $n$-permutation (in one-line notation) of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is a sequence of distinct numbers in $\{1,2,...,n\}$. We say that an $n$-permutation $\pi=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n$ has an ascend at $i$ if $\pi_i<\pi_{i+1}$. For example, $3567124$ has an ascend at location 1 because $3<5$. We say that an $n$-permutation $\pi$ avoids $321$ if we cannot find indices $i_1<i_2,i_3$ such that $\pi_{i_1}>\pi_{i_2}>\pi_{i_3}$. For example, $4321$ contains $321$ and $1234$ avoids $321$.

Let $D_n(k)$ denote the number of 321-avoiding $n$-permutations that start in an ascending run consisting of exactly $k$ elements. Prove that
$$D_n(k)={2n-k-1\choose n-1}-{2n-k-1\choose n}.$$

This is an exercise in the book by Miklos Bona (Combinatorics of Permutations). I need this result for a different problem that I have been working on. Does anyone know why this formula is true?

What I have so far is the following: Let $\pi=\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n$ be an $n$-permutation that avoids 321 and starts in an ascending run consisting of exactly $k$ elements. Then we have
$$\pi_1<\pi_2<\cdots<\pi_k>\pi_{k+1}.$$
Since $\pi$ avoids $321$, we have $\pi_j>\pi_{k+1}$ for all $j>k+1$. However, the relationship between $\pi_1,...,\pi_k,\pi_{k+2},...,\pi_n$ seems rather complicated. I don't see why we need $2n$ as in the formula.

Update: (7/8/2023) Prof. Bona pointed out that this is a lemma in a classical paper by Simion and Schmidt (1985):
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669885800524